# Resolution drops after rendering animations

Tags: rendering, animation, video, eevee-render-engine

The resolution of animations on my device look good in blender, but after rendering them the video quality drops greatly, even when increasing the sample rate. The first few frames, mostly of the still image also do not show any flaws, however, a few seconds in there's a great resolution drop. How can I fix this please?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/njRkp.png)

Comment: Possible framerate error? Maybe give your animation a higher framerate, or set the video quality to 150%

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the encoding quality setting that isn't preserved if rendering a still image as an animation.

For now a quick workaround is to set a constant bitrate for the encoder like so:

[image]